# How to compare the size of two times in Python, if two times have different sources？

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

（It may come from DataTime module, timedelta module of pandas, or datetime in numpy package）

For example:

```
first = numpy.datetime64('2019-04-02T12:18:00.000000000')

second = numpy.datetime64('2019-04-08T12:16:00.000000000')
```

if we compare "first - secone" to `pd.Timedelta("1H")` using `first - secone < pd.Timedelta("1H")` will arise an error:

> Cannot compare type Timedelta with type ndarray

I'm surely a novice and I hope to get some advice although this is a simple question. Thank you very much.
If possible, Can you guide me what keyword I should search to find the answer I want.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you cast the difference as `pd.Timedelta` too: `pd.Timedelta(first - second) < pd.Timedelta('1H')`

However, `first - second` is negative. Not sure whether that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I have solved my question, which had took me so many time!